# Tortoise svn update file after empty folder checkout

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I checked out empty folder from svn, then later on based on the need I want to update the file I need.

From command prompt, once we check out empty folder, we can use svn update filename.
How can we do the same in windows tortoise svn.

Regards,
Venkat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're referring to a so called "sparse checkout" that doesn't have all items of the repository fetched into the working copy.

Since you're using TortoiseSVN, you might want to read the section about [sparse checkouts](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html#tsvn-dug-checkout-depth) in the docs.

Note there are several ways for you to get the files you want:

- using the repository browser started from the working copy ("update to revision" in the context menu)
- from the check-for-modifications dialog after you clicked on the "check repository" button there's also the "update to revision" context menu entry
- from the explorer "update to revision" context menu entry, use the "Choose items..." button in the update dialog

I'm sure there are a few more ways, but they're not so obvious...

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this if what you're looking for, but navigate to the folder, right click it, and select "SVN Update".

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are having a empty folder checked out. Now you have added a file, Jus right click the file you added and TortoiseSVN -> Add. This will Add the file(Show a + symbol in your file). Then You can Right click the folder TortoiseSVN -> Commit. To Add the files to repository.

Comment: I don't want to add file to SVN. I want to check out single file when ever I need.

Comment: If the folder is empty how can you check out a file in empty folder. You have add a file first then only you can check out whenever you need.

Comment: I'm checking out empty folder from svn first. It will have just .svn hidden folder(svn information). From there onwards, I want to check out what I need later on.

Comment: Pls be sure of wat you are asking. Your are telling folder is empty means there is no file in the folder, Hw do you expect a file  to check out from empty folder.

Comment: Go through to this link to understand better about Tortoise SVN
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/